# Как преобразовать String в utf-8

Tags: android

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста как при чтении из txt файла текст преобразовать в utf-8, потому что выводятся символы "????" вместо букв? Когда в notepad набираю текст и в меню выбираю преобразовать в utf-8, читается нормально, но если в обычном блокноте, то выводятся вопросительные знаки. Помогите кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Спасибо!

```
            // получаем путь к SD
            File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            // добавляем свой каталог к пути
            sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" );
            // формируем объект File, который содержит путь к файлу
            File sdFile = new File(sdPath, getTeach.getText().toString());
            try {
              // открываем поток для чтения
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(sdFile), "UTF-8"));
              String str = "";
              str = br.readLine().toString();
              tv.setText(str);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно поможет

`String str = new String (br.readLine().toString().getBytes(),"UTF-8");`

по умолчанию String в Java имеет кодировку UTF-16, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: Благодарю за совет, но все равно вместо русских букв вопросительные знаки.